# How to add a label to a color using aes in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a simple ggplot command in my script file:

```
ggplot(myea_running, aes(x=DistanceMeters, y=AvgPace, 
   color=month(myea_running$StartTime))) + 
geom_point(aes(size = TotalTimeSeconds)) + 
geom_smooth() + 
ggtitle("Distance (m) over average pace (min / km)") + 
labs(x="Distance", y="Average pace")
```

and I would like to change the default color title that the above code generates. I looked through the documentation but did not find any relevant information on putting a title on a color code generated using the color attribute of the aes() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ggplot(myea_running, aes(x=DistanceMeters, y=AvgPace, 
       color=month(myea_running$StartTime))) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = TotalTimeSeconds)) + 
  geom_smooth() + 
  ggtitle("Distance (m) over average pace (min / km)") + 
  labs(x="Distance", y="Average pace",
       color = "Month", size = "Total Time in Seconds")
```

For transparency issue with four variables, modify your code like this:

```
geom_point(aes(size = TotalTimeSeconds), alpha = 0.4)
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you! I do program D3 for a while but with R and ggplot2 plotting is just so simple and straightforward ...

Comment: Thank you, Hadley Wickham, for making our plot great again.

Answer (score 0):

The `aes` function only covers those things that reflect the different values of variables in your dataset.  The colour of a chart title is just a parameter for the chart, not an aesthetic.  You can change the color of the title by adding `+ theme(plot.title = element_text(color="blue"))` to the ggplot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the legend title, use `ggplot2` [guides](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/guide_legend.html):

```
ggplot(myea_running, aes(x=DistanceMeters, y=AvgPace,
    color=month(myea_running$StartTime))) +
  geom_point(aes(size = TotalTimeSeconds)) +
  geom_smooth() + ggtitle("Distance (m) over average pace (min / km)") +
  labs(x="Distance", y="Average pace") +
  guides(color = guide_legend(title = "New Title"))
```